# How to handle unknown HTTP methods hitting a rails app in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, postman

I have a rails application in production and some bots try to send unknown non standard HTTP methods which are not defined in the action_dispatch gem for which an exception gets thrown

ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod - PURGE, accepted HTTP methods are OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK, VERSION-CONTROL, REPORT, CHECKOUT, CHECKIN, UNCHECKOUT, MKWORKSPACE, UPDATE, LABEL, MERGE, BASELINE-CONTROL, MKACTIVITY, ORDERPATCH, ACL, SEARCH, MKCALENDAR, and PATCH:

I tried using middle wares and rescuing the exception but nothing seemed to work.

Edit:
this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38998) on the rails is similar to what I am facing but still no solution there as well:

Comment: Thank you but I read this issue:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38998

this is exactly similar to my case I think I have to fix this on ngninix.

Comment: Yea sorry for that but still It didn't help much.

Comment: maybe you don't need to do anything... who cares that a bot sees an exception? We all experience these attacks and the fact that there isn't a readily-available solution suggests that we can just ignore them!

Comment: Sounds like server level rather than application.

Comment: If you want to handle this on the Rack server level you can use the [Rack::Attack](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack) gem which lets you filter requests before they reach your Rails app. This is less efficient than doing it a step up in for example nginx or apache but it lets you write the rules in Ruby.

Comment: Also if you attempted something then show that attempt - "I tried something but it didn't work" is probably the least useful thing you can say as a programmer and comes off as a lazy attempt to get someone else to do your work for you.

Comment: @max I will keep that in mind next time.